# VBA: RecordSet values overwritten by MoveNext

Tags: sql, vba, iteration, recordset

I've encountered a strange problem during some work with VBA and a DAO.Recordset.
I'm currently looping throgh the recordset and save the corresponding fields for earch iteration in an array.
But every time I call ".MoveNext" due to the while-loop, the information stored in the "rs.Fields.Field(i).Value" is being overwritten, thus the fields are unusable. I've figured this out during debugging.

Some relevant code:

```
If Not rs Is Nothing Then
      If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        With rs
            While Not .EOF
                ReDim Preserve fieldSet(0 To i + 1) As DAO.Fields
                Set fieldSet(i) = rs.Fields
                i = i + 1 ' the values are still intact at this point
                .MoveNext ' here's where there's only "No current record" stored inside the value-field
            Wend
        End With
      End If
```

Hopefully somebody has an idea what causes this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you will be moving to the `next record` the fields will be reset to the next record.. What do you mean by this? `rs.Fields.Field(i).Value`? or do you mean `rs.Fields(i).Value`?

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  All you're doing is copying a **reference** to rs.fields into your array. So, all members of the array will point to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try running another loop within for the field/column count in each record:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
   For j = 0 to rs.Fields.Count
     Set fieldSet(j) = rs.Fields.Field(j).Value 
     '-- do stuff
   Next j
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: @Remou would have given you a better idea :)